# WPF trigger for TextBox.Text doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a dependency property in my user control called `IsPromptShown`:

```
public static DependencyProperty IsPromptShownProperty = DependencyProperty.
    Register("IsPromptShown", typeof(bool), typeof(AutoCompleteSearchBox), new 
    PropertyMetadata(true));

public bool IsPromptShown
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsPromptShownProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IsPromptShownProperty, value); }
}
```

That custom control contains a `TextBox`. That text box doesn't have any value assigned to its `Text` property:

```
<TextBox Name="_searchTextBox" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    GotFocus="SearchTextBox_GotFocus" LostFocus="SearchTextBox_LostFocus" 
    TextChanged="SearchTextBox_TextChanged"/>
```

Now I'm setting the following trigger in the hosting window:

```
<Trigger Property="IsPromptShown" Value="True">
    <!--<Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic"/>-->
    <Setter Property="TextBox.Text" Value="Seek"/>
</Trigger>
```

The commented line that sets `FontStyle` works but the second that sets `TextBox.Text` doesn't. I also have been trying to set `Foreground` property and that also have failed. What is going on?

Comment: how did you set the dataContext in the hosting window? set the Trigger on the textBox itself instead of the window

Comment: @makc _TextBox_ doesn't see _IsPromptShown_ dependency property which is visible only on my custom control level. Is there a capability of declarating dependency property for internal text box?

Comment: define internal Textbox, i am missing the whole picture... i am guessing but maybe attached property will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It is not trivial, but works. Assume that we have a custom `UserControl` that contains a `TextBox` and ather controls. We want to be capable of assigning style to each internal control depending on some `bool UserControl.IsSomething` dependency property. First we have to declare another dependency property `Style UserControl.AlternativeStyle`. Then we attach an event handler to `IsSomething` in order to toggle current `Style` and `AlternativeStyle` when `IsSomething` changed:

```
public static DependencyProperty AlternativeStyleProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "AlternativeStyle",
        typeof(Style),
        typeof(MyUserControl));

public Style AlternativeStyle
{
    get { return (Style)GetValue(AlternativeStyleProperty); }
    set { SetValue(AlternativeStyleProperty, value); }
}

public static DependencyProperty IsSomethingProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "IsSomething",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(MyUserControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(true, IsSomethingProperty_Changed));

public bool IsSomething
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsSomethingProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IsSomethingProperty, value); }
}

private static void IsSomethingProperty_Changed(
    DependencyObject d,
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Swap styles
    // e.g.
    // var tempStyle = Style;
    // Style = AlternativeStyle;
    // AlternativeStyle = tempStyle;
}
```

The harder part is about setting `AlternativeStyle` outside the custom `UserControl`. Below is how to achieve that in XAML of window that hosts our custom control:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="DefaultTextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="DefaultUserControlStyle" TargetType="local:MyUserControl">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultTextBoxStyle}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="AlternativeUserControlStyle" TargetType="local:MyUserControl" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultUserControlStyle}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultTextBoxStyle}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="local:MyUserControl" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultUserControlStyle}">
        <Setter Property="AlternativeStyle" Value="{StaticResource AlternativeUserControlStyle}"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

The above style will be added automaticly to all instances of `MyUserControl` and when we change `IsSomething` value, then alternative style will be applied to the owner of changed `IsSomething`.

Answer (score 3):

I had problems similar to this when I started using WPF. You just have to look at things in a different way. Instead of looking at the value of the `IsPromptShown` property and trying to change a property of the `TextBox` in a `Trigger` in the `UserControl`, do it the other way around. Look at the value of the `IsPromptShown` property and try to change the property of the `TextBox` in a `Trigger` in the `TextBox`.

```
<TextBox Name="_searchTextBox" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    GotFocus="SearchTextBox" LostFocus="SearchTextBox_LostFocus" 
    TextChanged="SearchTextBox_TextChanged">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="TextBox.Text" Value="Default value if required" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsPromptShown, ElementName=This}" 
                    Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="TextBox.Text" Value="Seek" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Note that for this to work, you will need to add `Name=This` to the declaration of your `UserControl`. This just lets the Framework know where to find the `IsPromptShown` property... you could just as easily use a `RelativeSource Binding` for this if you prefer.

Comment: That is an idea, but I need a solution that allows to set trigger content outside the custom control and also there should be capability of changing styles of other internals of custom control, not only TextBox.

Comment: That will allow that... just set the `IsPromptShown` property from outside the `UserControl`. And try fixing one problem per post... your question title is `WPF trigger for TextBox.Text doesn't work`. Add a new post for any other problems.

Answer (score 1):

I think the Problem is that you can´t access the TextProperty of the Textbox in your UserControl from outside!

Try creating a Text DependencyProperty that sets the Value of the Textbox inside the UserControl and set this Property in the Trigger!

Comment: But then I will have to expose all styling possibilites each of which in separate dependency property. I want to have one boolean property and allow user to set style from outside depending on value of that property. He maight display some text but also change color or other styles for other controls.